# howto draw a text with alignment centered in simpliest way. (ios , swift)

Tags: ios, swift, drawing

I would like to draw a text in my custom view at point X,Y with center allignment. In case the text would be "SUGUS", I expect to have the Character G at Point X,Y.

I tried several things with NSString.drawinRect(), where I have to provide the width of the text, which has to be measured first depending on the Fonttype. It worked, but for me thats not a straightforward solution.

I purposely did not add code here, because a first try with code was misleading and I hope someone can help me with a clean simple solution ?

Comment: Provide a bounding box much larger than your expected text frame, center it on the X,Y, and then set your text alignment to centered before drawing. It'll figure itself out.

Comment: Thats exactly what I do. I set the width to 1000. But I have a bad feeling with it and I am not sure if this is best practice ?

Comment: Your text has a maximum bounds (i.e., you probably don't want to draw outside the view). If you always want to center within this maximum, this is the easiest way to do it. It is not bad practice to do so; it is expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirmation. Probably you could answer that way and I would accept if you like.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, How do you set the alignment to be centered? I didn't know you could do this when drawing into a UIView.

Comment: You can set the `alignment` of `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` on an `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, thanks for the info. I missed that one.